# Is there an python function or extension that is is similar to Matlab's format short?

Tags: python, matlab, rounding

The command format short in Matlab makes all the print outs in the command window be "Short, fixed-decimal format with 4 digits after the decimal point."

I know there is np.round, but I would like to have this functionality that Matlab offers in python so I dont have to write round every time. This in order to get a better overview of arrays/dataframes when they are printed.

I am interested in automatic **rounding of numbers/floats** printed in the terminal without using np.round

Ideally I would like also to be able to choose the number of digits (4).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), from the documentation:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
np.array([1.123456789])
[1.1235]
```